# create temporary table in mysql

Tags: java, mysql

guys is that possible to use temporary table inside temporary table in mysql ??
as when i use

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE bo_attribute_description_group_temp (
    SELECT id 
    FROM bo_attribute_description_group
    WHERE display_name IN ('backoffice.attr.group.services', 'backoffice.attr.group.eyecatchergroup')
);

select * from bo_attribute_description_group_temp;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE bo_attribute_description_temp (
    SELECT id
    FROM bo_attribute_description
    WHERE group_id IN (bo_attribute_description_group_temp)
);
```

but it gives me

```
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'bo_attribute_description_group_temp' in 'where clause'    0.000 sec
```

why ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. You must use a select clause in the second create table sub-query:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE bo_attribute_description_group_temp (SELECT id
                                                        FROM bo_attribute_description_group
                                                        WHERE display_name IN ('backoffice.attr.group.services', 'backoffice.attr.group.eyecatchergroup'));

select * from bo_attribute_description_group_temp;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE bo_attribute_description_temp (SELECT id
                                                  FROM bo_attribute_description
                                                  WHERE group_id IN (select id from bo_attribute_description_group_temp));
```